# Python: Read multiple files and move them to a directory according to their content

Tags: python

I am quite new to python, but I would like to use it for the following tasks:

1. read all files in a directory
2. look for a specific character in all lines of the files
3. if this character is present only once in the file copy the file in a specific directory.

I tried the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import glob
import shutil



path = '/xxxx/Dir/*.txt'   
files=glob.glob(path)   
for file in files:     
    f=open(file)  
    f.read()
    total = 0
    for line in f:
        if "*TPR_4*" in line:
            total_line = total + 1
            if total_line == 1:
                shutil.copy(f, 'xxxx/Test/')
f.close()
```

However, it is not working.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Does it copy if you make it always pass the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is not quite correct, also you are mixing up `total` and `total_line` and `shutil.copy` takes the name, not the object as an argument. And note that the `if .. in line` does not use globbing syntax, i.e. to search for `TPR_4`, use `'TPR_4'`, not `'*TPR_4*'`. Try the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/python    
import glob
import shutil

path = '/xxxx/Dir/*.txt'   
files=glob.glob(path)   
for file in files:     
    f=open(file)
    total = 0
    for line in f:
        if "TPR_4" in line:
            total += 1
            if total > 1:
                break  # no need to go through the file any further
    f.close()
    if total == 1:
        shutil.copy(file, 'xxxx/Test/')
```

Comment: What specifically is not working? I tried it on a test set of files and it did what I understood it was supposed to do.

Comment: I have a file that contains just one line with the string TPR_4. In the folder Dir there are then more .txt file. I run it and the Test folder is empty, wherease the above mentioned file sould be there.

Comment: Ah, so you are not looking for the string `"*TPR_4*"` but simply for `"TPR_4"`? In this case, no need to have the asterisks there, it's not a globbing pattern. Oh and I understood it that you also wanted to exclude files that have more than one line with the string in it. If you have at most one line like this, the code can be simpler.

Comment: No you are right I want exclude the files that have more than once the pattern.

Comment: Got it it seems to work! Thanks a lot, accept and thumb up in once!

Answer (score 2):

`shutil.copy()` takes file names as arguments not open files. You should change your call:

```
shutil.copy(file, 'xxxx/Test/')
```

Also: `file` is a poor name choice. It's a built-in function's name.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code for your question, maybe it's good for you.

```
import os, shutil

dir_path = '/Users/Bob/Projects/Demo'
some_char = 'abc'
dest_dir = "/Users/Bob/tmp"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for _file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, _file)
        copy = False
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            while True:
                line = f.readline()
                if not line:
                    break
                if str(line).find(some_char) > -1:
                    copy = True
                    break
            if copy:
                shutil.copy(file_path, dest_dir)
                print file_path, ' copy...'
```